# Google Sheets: NOW Formula Populating Numeric Value Only

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to add a NOW statement in my IF formula. Its working but populating numeric values only, see formula below:

`=IF(D3="","",NOW())&"-Login Details and Tablet have been sent to partner"`

Result: 44005.4947026389-Login Details and Tablet have been sent to partner

Comment: I have tried formatting the cell using the following formats: Date, Date Time & Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're getting refers to the quantity of days passed since December 30, 1899. When you concatenate this date with other content, the cell is not being interpreted as a date, so the date is not getting formatted according to your preferences.

To format this date, you could use [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) (check the **Notes** to see the possible formatting options for this). See, for example, this:

```
=IF(D3="","",TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd_hh:mm:ss"))&"-Login Details and Tablet have been sent to partner"
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!